# Segmentation fault on recursive merge sort

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I'm trying to write a fully recursive version of merge sort
I get segmentation fault on `merge` function when I try to order more than 100k records, I read online that it would be a stack overflow issue, related to VLAs, but I can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _MBArray MBArray;

struct _MBArray {
    void ** array;
    int length;
};

void mergeSort(MBArray *mbarray, int start, int end, int (*compare)(void *, void *)) {
    if (start == end) {
        return;
    } else {
        int middle = (end + start) / 2;
        mergeSort(mbarray, start, middle, compare);
        mergeSort(mbarray, middle + 1, end, compare);
        merge(mbarray, start, middle + 1, end, compare, (mbarray->array)[middle + 1]);
        return;
    }
}

void merge(MBArray *mbarray, int startA, int startB, int length, int (*compare)(void *, void *),void *elem) {
    if (startA > startB - 1) {
        return;
    } else
    if (startB > length) {
        return;
    } else
    if ((*(compare))((mbarray->array)[startA], (mbarray->array)[startB])) {
        merge(mbarray, startA + 1, startB, length, compare, (mbarray->array)[startB]);
        return;
    } else {
        memcpy(mbarray->array + (startA + 1), mbarray->array + startA, (startB - startA) * sizeof(void *));
        (mbarray->array)[startA] = elem;
        merge(mbarray, startA + 1, startB + 1, length, compare, (mbarray->array)[startB + 1]);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which VLA? I can't spot a VLA in the recursive functions

Comment: mbarray is declared with malloc, so if I'm not mistaken it's a vla

Comment: No, an array created using `malloc` is not a VLA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` and `mergesort` functions are incorrect:

- the `mergesort` function is given index values into the array such that `start` is included and `end` is excluded. Here is how to fix it:

```
void mergeSort(MBArray *mbarray, int start, int end,
               int (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        mergeSort(mbarray, start, middle, compare);
        mergeSort(mbarray, middle, end, compare);
        merge(mbarray, start, middle, end, compare);
    }
}
```

The `merge` function should be simplified. If you really intend for this function to recurse instead of using a temporary array, you might recurse as many as `length/2` times hence are likely to cause a stack overflow even faster than by allocating a VLA in the merge function.

Here is a VLA based `merge` function:

```
void merge(MBArray *mbarray, int low, int middle, int end,
           int (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
    int templen = middle - low;
    void *temp[templen];
    memcpy(temp, mbarray->array + low, sizeof(temp));
    int i = 0, j = middle, k = low;
    while (i < templen) {
        if (j >= end || compare(temp[i], mbarray->array[j])) {
            mbarray->array[k++] = temp[i++];
        else
            mbarray->array[k++] = mbarray->array[j++];
    }
}
```

A *fully recursive* version should save the element and recurse before setting it into its final position. This is much more costly in stack space than allocating a VLA so **stack overflow** is more likely. Allocating a temporary array once with `malloc()` and passing it to `mergesort` is much safer and also more efficient.

Here is a modified *fully recursive* `merge` function:

```
void mergeRecur(MBArray *mbarray, int dest, int a0, int a1, int b0, int b1,
                int (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
    if (a0 < a1) {
        if (b0 >= b1 || compare(mbarray->array[a0], mbarray->array[b0])) {
            void *temp = mbarray->array[a0];
            mergeRecur(mbarray, dest + 1, a0 + 1, a1, b0, b1, compare);
            mbarray->array[dest] = temp;
        } else {
            void *temp = mbarray->array[b0];
            mergeRecur(mbarray, dest + 1, a0, a1, b0 + 1, b1, compare);
            mbarray->array[dest] = temp;
        }
    }
}

void merge(MBArray *mbarray, int low, int middle, int end,
           int (*compare)(void *, void *))
{
    mergeRecur(mbarray, low, low, middle, middle, end, compare);
}
```

For large arrays, I would recommend allocating a temporary array once and calling a recursive version of `mergesort` that uses the temporary array instead of allocating a VLA:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _MBArray {
    void ** array;
    int length;
};

void mergeTemp(MBArray *mbarray, int low, int middle, int end,
               int (*compare)(void *, void *), void **temp)
{
    int templen = middle - low;
    int i = 0, j = middle, k = low;

    memcpy(temp, mbarray->array + low, sizeof(*temp) * templen);
    while (i < templen) {
        if (j >= end || compare(temp[i], mbarray->array[j])) {
            mbarray->array[k++] = temp[i++];
        else
            mbarray->array[k++] = mbarray->array[j++];
    }
}

void mergeSortTemp(MBArray *mbarray, int start, int end,
                   int (*compare)(void *, void *), void **temp)
{
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        mergeSortTemp(mbarray, start, middle, compare, temp);
        mergeSortTemp(mbarray, middle, end, compare, temp);
        mergeTemp(mbarray, start, middle, end, compare, temp);
    }
}

void mergeSort(MBArray *mbarray, int (*compare)(void *, void *)) {
    if (mbarray->length > 1) {
        void **temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp) * (mbarray->length / 2));
        mergeSortTemp(mbarray, 0, mbarray->length, compare, temp);
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: with fully recursive version I've still got segmentation fault on 20 mln records, so I will use "iterative" versione one

Comment: @Alee: for large arrays, use the last one with a temporary array allocated from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to merge() calling itself for each element merged. It would be better to have an entry function for mergeSort() that does a one time allocation of a second array (of pointers), then pass the second array as a parameter to a recursive MergeSortR(), and merge back and forth between the two arrays.

Comment: The second array can also be used as temporary storage for each merge stage. It is more tricky to use back and forth full merge phases and I am not convinced the performance is improved. Switching to insertion sort for small chunks is the dominant factor for performance improvement in my own experience. Do you have statistical data to support it?

Comment: @chqrlie - the main point of my answer is that merge() calls itself for every element merged (n-1 recursive calls for n elements). As for back and forth merging, it's not that complicated for top down (recursive) if there is an initial copy done as shown in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) .